# SOAP Web Service call from Java class

Tags: python, java, spring, spring-boot, soap

We have a Python code where we are calling to SOAP API and getting the response.
But as per the requirement we need to migrate the python code to JAVA class, since I am new to SOAP API, I am not sure how to migrate.

Added Python code sample below:

```
from suds.client import Client
from suds import WebFault
import datetime as dt
import base64
import time
import os
import sys


url= "https://www.test.com/service?wsdl"
client = Client(url, location=url, timeout=5000, nosend=False)

user = test
pwd = 123365

portList = []
port1 = client.factory.create('PortSelect')
port1.PortName = "Test_Port"
port1.PortOwner = "TEST"
portList.append(port1)

pa = client.factory.create('PortAna')
pa.PortSelectionList = portList
pa._Name = "TEST"

exportArgs = client.factory.create('ExpArgs')
exportArgs.PortAna = pa

exportType = client.factory.create('ExpType').PORT
try:
    print ('Create Set')
    id = client.service.CreateExportId(user, pwd, True, exportType, exportArgs)
    print (id)

    print('Downloading file...')
    attach = client.service.GetExportData(id)
        
    zip = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), attach.FileName)
    byte = base64.b64decode(attach.BinaryData)
    try:
            with open(zip, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(byte)
                f.flush()
                f.close()
    except:
            with open(os.path.basename(zip), 'wb') as f:
                f.write(byte)
                f.close()
except WebFault as details:
    print (details)
```

Kindly suggest how I can migrate to JAVA class.

Comment: There are a couple of articles that will get you going assuming you use Spring and/or Spring Boot. One is [here](https://www.baeldung.com/java-soap-web-service) and the other is [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service).